# Finding a mural of an unknown cathedral?

Tags: catholicism, symbolism, art, iconography

I am looking for the name of the cathedral that contains the following mural.

What I know for sure is:

- That it has been done between 2004 and 2008, more likely in 2008.
- It was made in a Catholic cathedral of a Spanish speaking country.
- The original file name is "2B CS.jpg"

What I think I know is:

- It was a city in Latin America.
- The city is on or near the seashore.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to narrow it down to a specific continent or region of the world? Any other clues besides Spanish-speaking?

Comment: I am afraid that anything other I say will take people to the wrong track. I think it is in Latin America but I am not 100 % sure and if I remember good it is somewhere on the shore but again I am not sure :( I tried everything from searching with reverse image search to writing to the Vatican and asking if they have an expert.

Comment: Oh yes there is one more thing: I think the mural was made between 2004 and 2008 probably in 2008.

Comment: How do you know all these facts and not know where it was? Can you ask whoever you got the picture from?

Comment: Hi, sure I can explain it. I have read an article ten years ago about this cathedral and there were couple of photos in the article. I saved this photo but not the info where it is from and who made it!

Comment: The symbolism would probably be interesting.

Comment: A reverse google image search reveals that this is a painting.

Comment: How does that help Andrew? Everything is a painting. Mural is a painting. One does need reverse google image to realise that.